# Is there some predictability in (pseudo-)randomness?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

I was wondering if random numbers actually do have some predictability.  For example, the digits of $ \pi$ are supposedly random.  However, the frequency of some digits "lags" that of other digits.  For example, if I take $1$ million digits of $\pi$, there are not $100,000$ of each of the digits $0$ thru $9$.  Does that mean that possibly the lagging digits are more likely to occur to balance things out?  If so, then it seems that the next "random" digit of $ \pi$ can be be predicted with greater than $10$% confidence.

It might be fun/cool if someone wrote a computer program and tried to predict the next digit of pi based on number frequency seen so far (biasing towards the lagging ones that are "due").  I wonder if after maybe $1$ million predictions if the % correct will exceed $10$% and by how much.

So my question is might this technique work to help predict "random" digits or has it been tried and it failed?

Comment: You might be interested in normal numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: Your question is essentially the [gambler's fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).  I think reading this link will clarify matters for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about digits of $\pi$, but if you have a truly random generator, then "lags" of certain digits will not correct themselves.

By that I mean the following:

Say you have a random generator that returns integers from $0$ to $9$, and say that in the last one million tries, the generator generated $200.000$ nines. Then the probability of the generator generating another nine in the next step is still $\frac1{10}$, meaning that the probability that there will be less nines than other numbers in the *next* million integers generated is exactly the same as it would be if the generator produced zero nines in the first million tries.

Comment: But the "law of averages" ("law of randomness") implies that lagging digits SHOULD "correct" themselves and that appears to happen in pi.  Take the digit $0$ for example.  It appears $8$ times in the first $100$ digits (lagging already), $93$ in the first $1,000$ (catching back up), $968$ in the first $10,000$ (even better), and $9,999$ in the first $100,000$ (almost perfect).  So my algorithm seems like it should work when predicting $0$s if I start it after the first $10$ or even first $100$ digits of pi.

Comment: Also, if there is a huge bias in the "random" number generator as in your example, then it is suspect if it is truly random.  Also, when does this happen in real life?  What normal number has a naturally occurring huge bias?  Certainly pi doesn't.

Comment: Also, your statement is contradictory to probability (short run vs. long run).  For example, in fair coin flips, one may see a run of $10$ heads early on, but in the longrun, that should balance out to $50/50$.  Using your philosophy, once the tails lag, they will never catch up.  I know what you are trying to say but I just think the way you are saying it is misleading. Long term probability shouldn't care if you get off to a biased start because it should eventually balance out. So my algorithm is trying to take advantage of that.

Comment: @David What I meant by never catching up is this. If you take a random generator and it *happens* to generate one million nines in a row, then the chance that it will generate a nine in the million-and-first try is still one in $10$. The generator does not suddenly decide to stop producing nines just because it made a million already.

Comment: @David: In the real world, if a slot machine gives us 200 nines in a row it is certainly very reasonable to expect another nine to appear.  That's because we'd assume that the machine is broken.  This is logical, because the chance the machine is broken is vastly larger than the chance that we see 200 nines in a row.  But for the purposes of this argument we are *assuming* that the machine is truly random.

Comment: $\pi$ has six $9$s in a row WAY before its statistical expectation.  I wonder if $\pi$ is "broken".

Answer (score 0):

I think the "pseudo-random" nature of the digits of $\pi$ is confusing the issue here.  It's perfectly conceivable that the digits of $\pi$ behave in the fashion you indicate - that it would be more likely for a digit to show up if it hadn't been seen in a while.  But if this were the case, the digits would not be behaving in a truly random way.

Let's say you flip a fair coin one billion times.  In the real world, all coins are biased one way or another, but here we're doing math, so we can assume it is in fact perfectly fair. Let's say that the first 200 flips were all heads. The law of large numbers tells us that we should expect that the percentage of heads will tend to go downward toward 50%.  But this should not be thought of as a mystical force that compels the coin to be tails - remember, we are *assuming* that each time we flip there is still a 50% chance of heads.  Instead, consider that if the coin is fair, on the next $999,999,800$ flips we expect to find about $499,999,900$ and $499,999,900$ tails, giving a total of $499,999,900$ tails, $500,000,100$ heads.  Since the heads have a head start, we do expect to see slightly more heads than tails overall.  But compared to the large numbers at play here, the difference will be negligible:  We would expect 50.00001% heads.

The point here is that anything that happens in a *finite* number of flips is going to be ultimately insignifant.

Comment: Unless maybe by flipping it so many times we wore off the heads and tails markings so that then we cannot tell them apart.  That would be significant.